# PHP Loop to list all items in array, not just last

Tags: php, foreach

I have a bit of PHP code which gets information from a CSV file, stores it in an array, then displays the data in a HTML table. My code currently uses a series of for loops to display both the table headers (keys) and the table contents (steps). The problem I am having is i cannot work out how to get the code to loop through and list each array of information, at the moment it only shows the last one (amount to display specified by $x variable in the for each loop.

If anyone could help me to get more than one single value using a foreach loop in the table it would be much appriciated, my code is as follows:

```
<?PHP

// Deals with potential MAC line endings
ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);


// Define function to read info from .CSV
function readCSV($csvFile)
{
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) 
        {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
    }

// Locate the .CSV to read
$csvFile = '500.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);

// Uses first line of .CSV for keys
$keys = $csv[0];

// For loop to set how many arrays to print
for ($x=1; $x <=2; $x++) 
{
    $step = $csv[$x];
    foreach ($step as $k => $v)
    {
        $array[$keys[$k]] = $v;    
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    echo '</pre>';
}

// Use data from arrays to build HTML table
print "<table>";
// Header
print "<tr>";
for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)
{
    print "<th>$keys[$x]</th>";
}
print "</tr>";
//Field data
print "<tr>";
for ($x=0; $x <=10; $x++)
{
    print "<td>$step[$x]</td>";
}
print "</tr>";
```

Comment: `readCSV()` is not a native PHP function. It would help to see the definition of that. Aside from that though, you are only getting two rows (header plus one row of data) because you are explicitly only outputting two rows. Your loops are creating your columns, not your rows.

Comment: Why don't you iterate over the `$array`? Can you please post the print_r of it?

Comment: `$x <=2` should be `$x < count($csv)`

Comment: And `$step = $csv[$x];` just overwrites the variable so you only have one row. Your final display loop should be two nested loops, the same as the one where step is set.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`$array[$keys[$k]] = $v;`
to `$array[$x][$keys[$k]] = $v;` and use `$array` instead of `$step` in the last `for`.

And this just for keep it small:

```
print "<table>";
print "<tr><th>".implode("</th><th>",$keys)."</th></tr>";
foreach ($array as $arr){
    print "<tr><td>".implode("</td><td>",$arr)."</td></tr>";
}
print "</table>";
```